# h and hpp problem, wrong order of including

Tags: c++, header, include, compiler-errors

I am compiling a large project containing >500 classes. After compiling VS 2010 there have been no problems.  When using g++ (Code:: Blocks / Netbeans) under Windows the code will not compile with the following error:

```
library/source/algorithms/file/../../algorithms/graph/../algebra/../spheredistance
/file.hpp:31:51: fatal error: ../../exception/ErrorOverflow.h: No such file or directory. 
Compilation terminated.
```

However, this file exists in the specified path. Linux version works correctly. 
Character / or \ in the path does not matter (tested).

If I **change order of included files**, the above mentioned error disappears and a similar error appears elsewhere in the code...

I think that somewhere in the code there is a cyclic dependency or wrong order of included files.

File structure:

1) .cpp file

```
#include "file.h"
```

2) .h file

```
#ifndef file_H
#define file_H

template <typename T>
class Class 
{
};

#include "file.hpp"
#endif
```

3) .hpp file

```
#ifndef file_HPP
#define file_HPP

#include "../../somefile.h"

template <typename T>
class Class 
{

};

#endif
```

Most of header files *.h are included in *.hpp files, but in some *.h files there is a need for including another *.h file. A short and simplified example illustrating rounding on/off of the result:

```
Orientation.h
#ifndef Orientation_H
#define Orientation_H


typedef enum
{
    RoundOn, RoundOff
} TRound;


class Orientation
{
    public:
            template <typename T>
            static short getOrientation( const T dx1, const T dy1, const T dx2, const T dy2, const TRound round = RoundOff );
};
```

Some class Position: method gives round on / round off results

```
#include "Orientation.hpp"

Position.hpp
#ifndef Position_H
#define Position_H

#include "../orientation/Orientation.h"  //must be included for Rounding


class Position
{
    public:
            template <typename Point1, typename Point2>
            static unsigned short getPosition ( const Point1 * p, const Point2 * p1, const Point2 * p2, const TRoundType round );
};

#include "Position.hpp"

#endif
```

Please advise:

- which header/include policy is suitable for such a large project.
- how to find headers with the wrong order of including (if it is possible)
- how to reorganize this project to avoid above mentioned problems.

---

**UPDATED RESULTS:**

Thank you all for your helpful advice.

I am sorry, I was completely wrong. A bug was actually **in relative path** containing characters .. (double dot)

After rewriting all include directives is everything OK.

Comment: Circular dependency will never yield a error message like `fatal error: ../../exception/ErrorOverflow.h: No such file or directory`, The compiler is specifically telling you that it cannot find the file, either it is not present at that path, or the path is not correct.

Comment: Path exists and it is correct. Checking a correctness of the path is the wrong way.

Comment: You should not rely on header files being included in a particular order. The error message isn't telling you what you think it is.

Comment: @Cody: Could you explain, please, your comment in more detail? Thanks

Comment: @Johnas: Since you already decided on what is being suggested is wrong. You seem pretty competent to solve your problem.All the best!

Comment: @Als. Do not consider my previous comment as impolite, please. This code compiles on several compilers so the inappropriate path looks extremely unlikely.

Comment: All of those `../`s in the paths looks very dubious (and brittle). I work in an environment where the only allowed use of `../` is `#include "../include/some_header.h"`. Everything other #include must be of the form `#include "Path/Relative/To/Include_dir/some_header.h"`.

Comment: Personally I would have done a few things differently, the first of which would be to create an include directory at the root of the source tree and add it to the include path using `-I<dir>` or if you're using the GNU Autotools `-I$(top_srcdir)/include`.  In any case, using the root of the source tree as the root directory, please explain what the absolute paths of file.hpp and ErrorOverflow.h  are.  For example, it seems the path of "file.hpp" is `/library/algorithms/spheredistance/file.hpp`.  That means "ErrorOverflow.h" should be at `/library/exception/ErrorOverflow.h`.  Is it?

Comment: And if you're writing `#include "../exception/ErrorOverflow.h"` or something like it in `../../somefile.h`, it's no wonder your compiler isn't finding things.  You've essentially complicated your source tree.

Comment: @David>: If I edit a project file of NB7 project, Netbeans use this convention very frequently: <itemPath>../../../../../project/...

Comment: @Johnas: I suggest listening to people's advice when you've asked for it because you are unable to solve a problem yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and advices. I try to replace .. with the correct path and recompile the project...

Comment: I am sorry, I was completely wrong. A bug was actually in relative path containing characters .. (double dot). Thanks to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, this file exists in the specified path

No, it does not.

Although you're right in that cyclic inclusion can lead to some misleading error messages, this is not one of them.

One thing to bear in mind is that the resolution of inclusion paths is *implementation-defined* (2003:12.8/1), which may be why you're seeing inconsistency across toolchains. The use of relative paths is particularly curious. Simplify your source tree and inclusion paths, and this problem will go away.

Comment: I am sorry, I was completely wrong. A bug was actually in relative path containing characters .. (double dot). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Johnas: No problem. Let this be a lesson to you. :P